# Running a piece of code for a limited time

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I have been developing software for live messaging. At some point in my code, I create a ServerSocket object and wait for a client to connect to it.

```
...
ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(serverPort);
socket=serverSocket.accept();
...
```

Yet, if no client attempts to connect to the server in a specific amount of time, say 10 seconds, my code should be able to stop waiting for a client and keep running next lines. However, code stucks in `socket=serverSocket.accept();` until a client tries to make a connection. How can I avoid so?

Comment: Move socket=serverSocket.accept(); to another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the timeout for socket before accept as follows

```
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000); // 10 secs. time is in milisecs.
socket=serverSocket.accept();
```

This will block accept for 10 secs if no client it moves on.

But if you are planning to keep open the server socket, then create a new thread for accepting the client.